# Menu not creating in spreadsheet onOpen

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Am facing a problem in creating a menu in spreadsheet. where the same code works in another script. I dont know what am doing wrong. can someone please address it. It working when i run the function manually everytime.

function onOpen() {

```
var menu = [

{name: "Authorize", functionName: "authorize"},
{name: "Test", functionName: "testing"},
{name: "Notify", functionName: "notify"},
{name: "Clear", functionName: "clear"}
];  
ss.addMenu("Testing ", menu);  
}
```

where ss is declared outside.

Comment: Is it inside a library? Can you share whole onOpen() code? Try assigning it manually in Resources -> Triggers.

Comment: @Kriggs ya i tried it assigning manually and it works.

Answer (score 2):

I give an complete example about my code:

### New Google spreadsheet

```
 function onOpen() {
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
          .addItem('First', 'menu1')
          .addToUi();
    }

    function menu1() {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
         .alert('clicked');
    }
```

### Old Google SPreadsheet

```
 function onOpen() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var items = [
        {name: 'First', functionName: 'menu1'},
      ];
      ss.addMenu('My Menu', items);
    }

function menu1() {
  Browser.msgBox('clicked');
}
```

Comment: Thank you Hann. The code works. The problem in code is because of am using older version of code?

Answer (score 0):

Menu in spreadsheets may take a few seconds to appear. However if you do not see them, there's a possibility of some typo / bug in the code that is outside the onOpen() method.

Comment: ok amit. Thanks for the response. I will check the full code.